# Mithril ajax wrapper, m.request, converts failures to success

Tags: javascript, ajax, mithril.js

This may well be some newbie thing about JS and or Mithril that I am unaware of, but I have written a caching wrapper around Mithril's `m.request()` to track multiple pending requests with the intention of coalescing multiple identical requests (which concept fits very well with the backend RESTful API).

My wrapper function is this:

```
function sendRequest(sdrcfg,rqscfg) {
    var key=JSON.stringify(rqscfg);
    var ret=sdrcfg.cache[key];

    if(!ret) {
        var cleanup=function(dta) {
            delete sdrcfg.cache[key];
            sdrcfg.removed(key);
            if(Object.keys(sdrcfg.cache).length==0) { sdrcfg.completed(key); }
            return dta;
            };

        ret=m.request(rqscfg).then(cleanup,cleanup);

        if(Object.keys(sdrcfg.cache).length==0) { sdrcfg.activated(key); }
        sdrcfg.cache[key]=ret;
        sdrcfg.added(key);
        }
    return ret;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that when the `.then(cleanup,cleanup)` clause is present, any errors from the host are received by the success function of all subsequent `then()` clauses chained to the request with the net effect of converting a failure response to a success response for the downstream code.

If I simply comment out the then clause above, then the application code has the success or failure function called as expected.

It seems like a really straight-forward thing to want to do, and completely in line with Leo's example, but I am stumped. JS and, in particular, promises are new to me, so I don't know exactly how to use them, or if this is expected -- I am just following examples and trying to build on them.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be doing:

```
.then(cleanup, function(e) {
  cleanup()
  throw e; //re-reject for downstreams
})
```

Promise rejection is similar to a catch block, so once add a callback to handle it, it triggers the resolve callback for the rest of the chain.

---

Effective from Mithril 0.1.22, programmer Errors (like ReferenceError) are logged to the console if not handled. This reverts to the behavior of 0.1.19.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Did I miss this in your example, or does the example in the ["Wait for it" blog entry](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/wait-for-it.html) have the same fault?